# Application working on expo but crashes on physical device

Tags: react-native, build, expo, apk, ipa

I tried making builids recently but they didn't work. The apps with expo work fine but when I do the builds for android it opens expo go or it doesn't open the app but the expo image remains, for ios it crashes and doesn't open at all.

some infos:
expo doctor: all perfect
expo version: 49

my app.json:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Meal Pass",
    "slug": "mealpass",
    "version": "1.0.4",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./app/assets/meal-icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "scheme": "com.jawsdevelopers.mealpass",
    "jsEngine": "hermes",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./app/assets/mealpass.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "associatedDomains": ["applinks: com.jawsdevelopers.mealpass"],
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.jawsdevelopers.mealpass"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./app/assets/meal-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.jawsdevelopers.mealpass",
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "autoVerify": true,
          "data": [
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "com.jawsdevelopers.mealpass",
              "pathPrefix": "/login"
            }
          ],
          "category": [
            "BROWSABLE",
            "DEFAULT"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "owner": "jawsdevelopers",
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "<id>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

eas.json:

```json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.13.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

I have no idea what I need to show what files what configurations so if you want me to upload files comment and I will edit the application with files